# Clean the tags and quotes from a python/django string and make it a valid javascript string

Tags: javascript, python, regex, django, string

I have a text field named description in my django Model. I have stored a string in it that is

```
<p>Early cricket was at some time or another described as "a club striking a ball 
(like) the ancient games of club-ball, stool-ball, trap-ball, stob-ball".
<sup id="cite_ref-MTG_3-0" class="reference"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket#cite_note-MTG-3"><span>[</span>3<span>]</span></a></sup> 
Cricket can definitely be traced back to Tudor times in early 16th-century England.
 Written evidence exists of a game known as <em>creag</em> being played by <a title="Edward II of England" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_II_of_England">Prince Edward</a>,
 the son of <a title="Edward I of England" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_I_of_England">Edward I (Longshanks)</a>, 
at Newenden, Kent in 1301<sup id="cite_ref-4" class="reference"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket#cite_note-4">
<span>[</span>4<span>]</span></a></sup> and there has been speculation, 
but no evidence, that this was a form of cricket.</p>
```

I want to clean this string, want to remove all the HTML tags, double quotes and single quotes so that i can assign this string to a javascript variable. for this i wrote a template tag which returns the string after striping al html tags and replacing all the single and double quotes with None.

```
def clean_text(html_text):
    html=strip_tags(html_text)
    html=html.replace('"','')
    html= html.replace("'",'')
    print html
    return str(html)
```

but when I am trying to assign this string to a javascript variable i am getting error

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
console.log(Early cricket was at some time or another described as a club stri
```

I tried toString() method also but same result.
I tried to assign this to a variable but got the same error

```
var description = {{object.description|clean_text }}
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
A number of other words have been suggested as sources for the
```

register.filter('clean_text',clean_text)

Comment: I am using python/django for backend and Javascript for front end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap it in quotes.

```
var description = "{{object.description|clean_text }}"
```

However there is already a built-in filter which does exactly what you want, [`escapejs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs):

```
var description = "{{object.description|escapejs }}"
```

Comment: thanks , it works, before that also i wrapped it in double quotes but it didn't work at that time